# Do we able to get the replay log results from VuGen and get rendered on analysis report?

Tags: loadrunner

1. While we are executing the script on VuGen it will generate some replay log result.
2. Need to capture the results and get viewed on loadrunner analysis report for each transaction. 
   Could someone help me on this?

Comment: What is the question/error you are getting?

Comment: No, it's not an error. Just clarify, Is there is a way to get the log message on analysis report?

Comment: For example, if I got the page load time at VuGen log. That page load time we need to get displayed on loadrunner analysis report.

Comment: Don't enable logs for everything, only error.  Otherwise you will turn your local file system into a drag anchor, slowing the performance of every virtual user as they all contend for write access to the file system.   By the way, this is a fire-able offense in some practices